# Python Conditional on a date time Object

Tags: python

```
for index, row in HDFC_Nifty.iterrows():
    if HDFC_Nifty.iat(index,0).dt.year ==2016: 
        TE_Nifty_2016.append(row['TE'])
    else:
        TE_Nifty_2017.append(row['TE'])
```

Hello,

I am attempting to iterate over the DataFrame, more specifically apply a conditional to the Date column which is formatted as a Datatime object.

I keep getting the below error

**
TypeError: '_iAtIndexer' object is not callable
**

I do not know how to proceed further. I have tried various loops but am largely unsuccessful and not able to understand what I am doing incorrect.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use square brackets `[` `]` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html. `iat` is not a function but an indexable object.

Comment: Instead of `iterrows`, use `TE_Nifty_2016, TE_Nifty_2017 = [series.tolist() for _, series in HDFC_Nifty.groupby(df.iloc[:, 0].dt.year)["TE"]]`

Comment: `HDFC_Nifty[HDFC_Nifty.index.to_series().dt.year.eq(2016)]`